# Datepicker no muestra calendario y hora para seleccionar - No hace nada

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de añadir datetimepicker a una web con bootstrap, por algún motivo no funciona el desplegable para seleccionar fecha y hora, "no hace nada". ¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias.

**Librería en Head:**

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group" id="datetimepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Error en el dom:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por el error que te muestra no te estan cargando las librerias correctamente. Veo que has puesto mal la carga de los scripts, tienes que poner `src` no `source`

Comment: Disculpa Aitor, cierto que tenía eso mal puesto eso aquí en StackOverflow. Una vez corregido eso, devuelve error también. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Como te he puesto en el comentario, estas haciendo mal la carga de las librerias js y css.

Las CSS se hacen con `<link href=""/>` y las JS con `<script src=""></script>`.

Tienes alguno de los links escrito de manera incorrecto también, ya que con esas referencias aparece un error.

Te dejo un ejemplo con los las referencias correctas

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-sm-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#datetimepicker5" />
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Aitor por esas correcciones. Pero parece ser un tema de conflicto, ya que si coloco ese mismo código en la web (claro que $function etc. dentro de un script), no funciona. No estoy seguro si será que el template bootstrap tiene algunas referencias a otras versiones jquery, etc. y sea que haga que no funcione. No lo se la verdad, no domino jquery. Muchas gracias.